# Execute an Apex class

Tags: apex

I'm pretty new in Apex programming.
I've created a very simple class with a simple function. When I want to execute the class it gives me an error saying Unexpected token '(' . I did a lot of research but couldn't find an answer that works.

[image]

[image]

I also tried removing the parentheses while calling the function but then it gives me another error: Unexpected token EOF.

Does anyone have any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Providing code as images is discouraged because it's harder to read (especially if some of the lines are long), less accessible to screen readers, and forces people to retype it to try to reproduce the issue or write an answer that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you've shown us, this is just a simple error in calling a static method.

To call a static method, you need to use both the class name and the method name.

```java
// Static methods are called using <Class name>.<Method name>
// Note that the semicolon is also required
SampleClass.sampleFunc();
```

The anonymous apex isn't running inside of the apex class you have open in the dev console. It's not really running in *any* particular class, it's just running "in Salesforce". It's also the same language (Apex) as the rest of the code you might have in Salesforce, so it uses the same syntax.

Comment: Also note that if you want to see the result of calling your method, you'll need to store the return value in a string, and then `system.debug(<your string variable here>);`. Alternatively, you could just wrap your method call inside the `system.debug();` call.